# Building android build with jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I am trying to build android with Jenkin. But I am getting this compilation error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\android_build\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug: error: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).
```

Can anyone else facing this issue. I tried running the build on Android Studio and it works fine. I have defined the sdk path in jenkins and setup gradle also.

Please help.

Comment: Hey @Bipin Did you get any solution?

Comment: @A.R.  yeah I downgraded the jenkin version to 2.204.6 and suddenly it worked. and yeah also use app:build as task for build so you dont get lint error for other libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that worked for me. I was using jenkins:2.277.4, I downgraded the jenkin version to 2.204.6 and suddenly it worked. Also I used war file this time so the path to workspace was smaller as compared to previous install and yeah also use app:build as task for build so you dont get lint error for other libraries.